# Windows Phone 8 MVVM with JSON Deserialization

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

(Need suggestion about scary code)

I am trying to bring about some *elegance* to my old Windows Phone app code by incorporating MVVM and a generalized DataService class for all View Models, to call their corresponding web-service handlers.

For example, in notification ViewModel, I have:

```
private ObservableCollection<Notification> _notifications;
public ObservableCollection<Notification> Notifications
{
    get
    {
        return _notifications;
    }
}

public void GetNotifications()
{
    new DataService().DownloadViewModelData<ObservableCollection<Notification>>(GetNotificationsCallback, "getnotificationslist.ashx");
    this.IsDataLoaded = true;
}

public void GetNotificationsCallback(ObservableCollection<Notification> notificationsList)
{
    _notifications = notificationsList;
       
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Notifications");
    });
    this.IsDataLoaded = true;
}
```

In DataService class, I am trying to make a generic method to communicate with services:

```
public static string ServerUrl = "http://<ip-address>:<port>/";

public void DownloadViewModelData<T>(Action<T> callbackFunction, string handlerName, bool methodIsPOST = false, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> querySet = null) where T : class
{
    var queryString = "";

    if(null != querySet)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> tuple in querySet)
        {
            queryString += tuple.Key + "=" + tuple.Value + "&";
        }

        queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Length - 1, 1);
    }

    var urlQueryString = ServerUrl + handlerName;

    if (!methodIsPOST)
        urlQueryString += queryString;

    var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(urlQueryString);

    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> requestingMethod = null;

    if (methodIsPOST)
    {
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentLength = queryString.Length;
        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(
            a =>
            {

                System.IO.Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(a);
                byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString);
                postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, queryString.Length);
                postStream.Close();
                webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
                    b =>
                    {
                        using (WebResponse response = webRequest.EndGetResponse(b))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                callbackFunction(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)).ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream()) as T);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    null
                );
            },
            null
        );
    }
    else
    {
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
            a =>
            {
                using (WebResponse response = webRequest.EndGetResponse(a))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        callbackFunction(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)).ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream()) as T);
                    }
                }
            },
            null
        );
    }
}
```

## Questions:

1. Is it a right (modern) way of using lambda expressions and overall right approach to handle data layer for MVVM (given we have multiple models, views and view-models in our project)?
2. Would you recommend this approach for calling web-services in [Portable Class Library (PCL)](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/using-portable-class-libraries)?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there is a much nicer way of doing this so that your ViewModel does not know anything about the implementation of your data service.

There is a couple of things I would look into doing.

1. Start using a dependency injection framework like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). This will allow you to keep your ViewModel unaware of the type of data service it's using. You can use DI frameworks to inject specific implementations for you code.
2. Create an interface that represents your dataservice. For the sake of argument, I'll call my example `IDataService`. The primary goal of this interface is to abstract away the method in which the data is being retrieved. Thus the data could be access from a database, webservice or file with the viewmodel having any knowledge (or caring).

For your code, I'd give it the signature of:

```
public interface IDataService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Notification>> ListNotifications();
}
```

You'll notice I'm using `Task<>` which allows me to make use of the .Net 4.5 async framework. So now we an interface that just says, `I have  a way of returning a list of notifications, asynchronously`. THis is as much information as your viewmodel needs.

1. Don't recreate your `ObservableCollection<Notification>`. If you need to change the contents of the collection, `Clear()` it, then repopulate, but don't rebind  or recreate the collection itself. This has a number of performance benefits as well.
2. If you put the interface definitions in the portable library, then if you require specific implementations for specific platforms (eg. WP8 vs Win8), then as you are only referencing interfaces in your ViewModels, then you might only have to change a very small amount to support difference implmentations.

Hope that all makes sense.